# Talend control bus component

Tags: talend

I'm currently trying to figure out how to use the control bus component in Talend but I can't find any example on the internet. I can't access component directly like a cMessagingEndpoint for example. I tried many things but none of them work, I'm not really a Talend specialist.

If anyone could tell me what I have to do to use this component in order to monitor serveral routes, it would be very helpful.

Thanks to anyone who will try to help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way by putting a cMessagingEndpoint with this : "controlbus:route?action=stats". Good to know that in my case, each route has its own context si I can't get any stats from another route.